# Multiple object instantiation prevention

Tags: php, object-oriented, zend-framework

I have a class with a private variable used to store an object. 
I have a function that checks first if that variable already contains an object or not; if not, it instantiates the needed object and sets it to that variable, otherwise it just returns the content of that variable.

I was wondering if the `getSessionCustomer()` here is an overkill/unnecessary or if it has real benefits. I simply based this on the Album tutorial by Zend, but I haven't fully tested it out yet to really see the advantages (or disadvantages).

```
class JobController extends AbstractActionController
{
    private $SessionCustomer;

    public function saveJobAction()
    {
        $SessionCustomer = $this->getSessionCustomer();

        if(empty($SessionCustomer->offsetGet('customer_id'))) {
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('login');
        } else {
            $JobService = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Job\Factory\JobServiceFactory');
            $job_id     = $JobService->saveJob();

            return $this->redirect()->toUrl('/job/' . $job_id); 
        }
    }

    public function viewJobAction()
    {
        $sm                 = $this->getServiceLocator();
        $SessionCustomer    = $this->getSessionCustomer();

        if(empty($SessionCustomer->offsetGet('customer_id'))) {
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('login');
        } else {
            $JobTable       = $sm->get('Job\Model\JobTable');
            $JobItemTable   = $sm->get('Job\Model\JobItemTable');

            $jobId          = $this->params()->fromRoute('id');
            $Job            = $JobTable->getJobById($jobId);
            $JobItems       = $JobItemTable->getJobItemsByJobId($jobId);

            $this->layout()->setVariable('title', 'Order #' . $jobId);

            $viewModel = new ViewModel();
            $viewModel->setVariables(array(
                'Job' => $Job,
                'JobItems' => $JobItems
            ));

            return $viewModel;
        }
    }

    private function getSessionCustomer()
    {
        if(!$this->SessionCustomer) {
            $this->SessionCustomer = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Session\Customer');
        }

        return $this->SessionCustomer;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the check `if (!$this->SessionCustomer)` is not unusual even if a bit clunky. I would still be more explicit about it and use `if ($this->SessionCustomer === null)`. The `private $SessionCustomer;` member will be initiated to `null`.

More generally however, what you are using here is called an anti-pattern. [PHP Singletons are almost universally considered an anti-pattern](https://coderoncode.com/design-patterns/programming/php/development/2014/01/27/design-patterns-php-singletons.html). Singleton really is not something you should be using, as it's really unnecessary, what you really want is [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

When you want to use a single class instance during the lifetime of an object, you simply request the `\Session\Customer` type in your object's constructor, and use a Dependency Injection Container to make sure that the same instance is passed to all the instances of the `JobController` class:

```
class JobController
{
    private $sessionCustomer;
    public function __construct(\Session\Customer $sessionCustomer)
    {
        $this->sessionCustomer = $sessionCustomer;
    }
    public function saveJobAction()
    {
        // just use the private property
        if (empty($this->sessionCustomer->offsetGet('customer_id'))) {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

At this point, I would just like to comment that otherwise, there is really no reason to use OOP if you are not using constructor injection and just globally access things with a service locator (which is also a very bad pattern of its own, but that's for another topic). That code could be procedural.

Back to the topic: defining your requirements in the constructor allows for the calling code to decide that instance to pass to the JobController's constructor, reuse that instance, pass in a mock instance (because hopefully, you would be testing that class, which may necessitate for you to mock instances).

I generally use [Auryn](https://github.com/rdlowrey/auryn) as a Dependency Injection Container, but the usage generally consists on instructing a container to share an instance of a class:

```
$injector = new \Auryn\Injector;
// this is how you actually use a single instance of a class, through sharing it with a container
$injector->share($sessionCustomer);
$jobController = $injector->make('JobController'); // uses the shared instance
```